# How can we Run PHP files Within an ASP.NET Web Application with Integrated pipeline mode for IIS?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

we have an ASP.NET Web Application deployed on Microsoft IIS 7.5 Web Server.
Our Server is a Windows 2008 R2 Standard.

We were trying to install PHP on our Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server.

In order to be highly aware of how our application and server are configured, we decided to Manually Install PHP on the Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server by following the steps in the guide associated with the URL link below:

( http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13 )

Our PHP was Manually installed in the C:\PHPNonthreadsafe5p5 directory.

I placed the a PHP file within the ASP.NET application.  The PHP file is placed in the following directory:

D:\blahblah\ASPNETWebApplication\PHPModules\Phpinfo.php

However, when we entered the following URL, I get the 500 internal Server error:

> https://blahblah.blah.blah.com/PHPModules/Phpinfo.php

I have PHP 5.5 installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Server with IIS 7.5. Please indicate how I can run PHP files in an ASP.NET Web Application with Integrated Mode.

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe simply the php script leads to a fatal error dued to some difference between web services' configuration?

Comment: However, my <?php phpinfo(); ?> in the Phpinfo.php file.  It should work.